# Redraw gtk notebook tabs in different position

Tags: gtk

I have some data that can be organized in a matrix, so I display it as a Gtk::Notebook inside a Gtk::Notebook. The external Gtk::Notebook has tabs at the left and the internal Gtk::Notebook has tabs at the top. So it looks like this:

[image: How it looks]
However, our customer would like it to be like this:

[image: How it should look]
The important change being, that the tabs at the left should be below their current position by the height of one tab, so that the GUI looks more like a matrix.

Adding a dummy unclickable tab as the first tab on the left seems an easy solution, but it would have to be a blue tab like all non-selected tabs, and thus it wouldn't merge with the background (the colors are part of the approved design of the application, so they can't be changed).

I've read something about subclassing widgets and drawing them myself, but I don't know how I would begin to do that. I'll probably be reading about that in the meantime.

Any ideas on how to achieve this effect will be appreciated.